# Image not showing in the UI

Tags: android, imageview, android-xml

I have an image in the 3 folders res/drawable-hdpi/mdpi/ldpi 600*600 as resolution) and i have this XML file to show a textview and the image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/sipLabel"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/connected" android:src="@drawable/connected" android:layout_below="@id/sipLabel" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.35" android:gravity="center" 
         />
        </LinearLayout>
```

What could br the problem?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's the problem you're seeing?

Comment: @Jordan: the image is not displayed. Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: I believe it's the `fill_parent` tag set on your TextView's layout_height attribute. See my answer below for more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is your first tag in the `LinearLayout`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/sipLabel"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
```

Since `layout_height` is set to `fill_parent` this TextView is filling the LinearLayout vertically, leaving no room for the image. Try changing `layout_height` to `wrap_content`.

Also, a couple of other things:

- You're using `android:layout_below="@id/sipLabel"`, but this only works in a RelativeLayout. So this attribute is being silently ignored.
- While you can choose any `layout_weight` you want, `0.35` is pretty arbitrary. Since it's the only child in the LinearLayout with weight, it will receive all of the extra vertical space.
- You don't need to include the `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` on your TextView tag.

Comment: I just changed layout_height to wrap_content and it's working now. Thank you very much. XML files are very very sensitive :( .

Answer (score 1):

I think `layout_below` only applies for RelativeLayouts. Also, that `layout_weight="0.35"` looks mighty suspect, I don't think it means what you think it means. I think it must have an integer value.

Comment: i edited the XMl by deleting layout_weight="0.35", same problem, then i tested another time by deleting layout_below, same problem! any other idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `TextView` has a height of `fill-parent`, and the `LinearLayout` is not scrolling (unless is put into a `ScrollView` you can't see the lower parts), your `TextView` takes up the whole screen of the Activity, and the `ImageView` being under it is not visible.

So you can either

- put your whole `LinearLayout` into a
  `ScrollView`, and scroll down to see
  your image, or
- if your goal is to show the image at
  the bottom of the screen, and the
  whole place above it should be taken
  be the `TextView`, then a
  `RelativeLayout would be the best
  option.

**Update**
a working `RelativeLayout` soulution would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/sipLabel" android:text="@string/loremipsum1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/connected" android:src="@drawable/connected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@id/sipLabel" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So i switched to a RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout=> same problem. Then i just added a <ScrollView> also same problem! Have i to change image resolution? it's 600x600 now :\

Comment: That's because you still have your textview set to fill its parent.